# Jenkins; Execute script on first failure

Tags: powershell, jenkins, plugins, groovy, build

I want Jenkins to execute a Powershell script after a "first failure" of the current build occured.
So the script may not be triggered on the next subsequent "failure"-builds. 
Only when the build is successful again, the powershell script may be triggered again on the first failure afterwards.

I have been searching already in groovy scripts, to determine the first failure. But perhaps someone knows a plugin that has the option to execute a script on 'first failure'?

Any help appreciated.

kind regards,

Pieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have performed following setup:

- I start a powershell in a windows Batch command Build. With following parameter `-BuildNr $ENV:BUILD_NUMBER`
- In the powershell i'll calculated the previous build nr (simply -1 :) )
- With that previous build nr I get the result from the xml:

Get Result from PREVIOUS Jenkins job

```
$PreviousUrl         = "$($ProjectLink)/$($PreviousBuildNr)/api/xml"
[xml]$PreviousXML = Invoke-WebRequest $PreviousUrl -Method GET  -Headers 
$headers -UseBasicParsing
$PreviousResult = $PreviousXML.freeStyleBuild.result
```

From there on i can use the `PreviousResult` and (similar) the `currentResult` further in my powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

The currentBuild object has a point to the previous build.  When your current build fails, you could probably check the status of the previous build with `currentBuild.previousBuild.result`  If it was successful then you know this is the first time it's failed.  I didn't actually try that so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use curl (or something like it), try getting the content of both `http.../jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber`and `http.../jobname/lastFailedBuild/buildNumber`. If the result from `lastSuccessfulBuild` is greater than `lastFailedBuild`, you've had a success before your last failure.